# My website redirects to another website on Google searches

Tags: url, redirect, google-analytics, google-search

I'm not sure if my website has been hacked or what have happened.

When I do some searches on google in which my website should show up, my website with a different url name does. It maintains the title that appears on Google after doing the search and the description of it.

Moreover, when looking for "mywebsite" without "www." and ".com" on Google, my website shows up the first one but in 4th position the random website which sells glasses does, again having the title and description I have for my website.

I don't know what to do. Already contacted with Google analytics and checked .htaccess. If someone knows something related to this I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Do you have a Google Search Console (a.k.a. Google Webmaster Tools) Account  ? This will diagnose most problems with Google search. Plus this is a bit off-topic, there is a stackoverflow site for webmasters which would be better suited for this question.

Comment: Didn't know about the webmasters stackoverflow page. I'm going to ask it there, thank you for your help :)

Comment: [Cross-post](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/82261/17633) on Webmasters SE.